# Multiple Window.open methods but load new window in already existed window

Tags: window.open

I have multiple Buynow buttons on this [page](https://www.cbtforinsomnia.com/products-page/), every button has [window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method and every button opens new window when clicked.

Now what I need is if user clicks on Product 1 a new window opens and then when he clicks on product 2 another window opens instead of this how can I load product 2 content in product 1 window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to achieve this using `data-target`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.secure_payment a').each(function(){
        var links = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
        var splitss = links.split("'");
        jQuery(this).removeAttr('onclick');
        jQuery(this).attr('data-target', splitss[1]);
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
        var linkG = jQuery(this).attr('data-target');
        do_ajax_action(linkG);
        var myPopup = window.open( linkG , "Payment_gate", "width=775,height=500").focus(); 
  });
});
```